# How do I fix these memory leaks in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, calloc

I am working on a function which allocates memory into an array, and then I free it later. Oddly enough, valgrind is giving me this error:

```
==93== HEAP SUMMARY:
==93==     in use at exit: 11,160 bytes in 2,232 blocks
==93==   total heap usage: 44,310 allocs, 42,078 frees, 1,632,230 bytes allocated
==93==
==93== 11,160 bytes in 2,232 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==93==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==93==    by 0x10976F: FillHashMap (in /mnt/c/Users/Jordan/Documents/GitHub/flwg/flwp)
==93==    by 0x1092F1: main (in /mnt/c/Users/Jordan/Documents/GitHub/flwg/flwp)
==93==
==93== LEAK SUMMARY:
==93==    definitely lost: 11,160 bytes in 2,232 blocks
==93==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==93==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==93==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==93==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==93==
==93== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Dr. Memory is giving me a similar error:

```
Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000000008 8 byte(s)
# 0 testing               [C:/Users/Jordan/Documents/GitHub/flwg/FLWP-2.c:120]
# 1 main                  [C:/Users/Jordan/Documents/GitHub/flwg/FLWP-2.c:105]
Note: @0:00:01.195 in thread 14704
Note: instruction: mov    (%rax) -> %rax
```

The strcmp line of code is what causes it to break with Dr. Memory, although valgrind says I have issues even if I don't call this particular method.

```
void testing(struct wordConnections *header){
    header = header->nextRow;
    
    while(strcmp(header->word, "berk") != 0){ 
        header = header->nextRow; 
        if(header == NULL){
         printf("Failed");
         return; 
        }
    }
}
```

The code that runs is (the value and significance of numLetters + 1 is it is the length of the char* stored in the wordStorage, the value of numLetters is 4):

```
char** FillHashMap(struct wordConnections **(*HashMap)){
    int h = 0; 
    /* The Amount of words in each file, File 1, 2, 3 */
    int totalWordQuantity[3] = {132, 7420, 19829}; 
    /*the word that we test, we add by two because first 4: word, 5th: \n, 6th: \0*/
    char word[numLetters + 1]; 
    /*how many times we've changed the character*/
    int letterSpot = 0; 
    /*the character that goes through the file*/
    char c; 
    FILE *flwd = OpenFile(); 
    /* is it the first word of the line */
    int wordCount = 0; 
    int isFirst = 1; 
    char p = fgetc(flwd); 
    c = p; 
    /* So, this is a temporary word, who will store the row, so all of its category folks will be contained within it */
    char* rowWord = malloc(sizeof(char) * (numLetters + 1)); 
    /*This stores all of the words*/
    char** wordStorage = (char**)calloc(totalWordQuantity[numLetters - 2], sizeof(char*) * (numLetters + 1));
    int i = 0; 
    /* First, take the character */
    while((c = p) != EOF){
        
        p = fgetc(flwd);

        /* Add the character to the word */
        word[letterSpot] = c; 
        /* Allows the letter spot to find the next place into the word */
        letterSpot++; 
        
        /* Determines if the character is the placement immediately after the word */
        if((c == ' ' && p != '\n') || c == '\n'){
            
            letterSpot = 0; 
            /* Throws in the \0, converting into a string */
            word[numLetters] = '\0'; 
            
            wordStorage[wordCount] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (numLetters + 1));
            h++;
            strcpy(wordStorage[wordCount], word); 
                
            /* Determine if it's the first word */
            if(isFirst == 1){
                strcpy(rowWord, word); 
                 
                /* Throw it in as a row */
                AddRow2DLL(wordStorage[wordCount], 
                         HashMap[FirstHashFunction(word[0])/*First Letter*/]
                                [SecondHashFunction(word)]/*First Vowel*/);     
            }
            /* If it's not the first word */
            else {
                AddColumn2DLL(wordStorage[wordCount], 
                       HashMap[FirstHashFunction(rowWord[0])/*First Letter*/]
                              [SecondHashFunction(rowWord)]/*First Vowel*/); 
            }
            
            if(c == ' '){
                isFirst = 0; 
            }
            if(c == '\n'){
                isFirst = 1; 
            }
            wordCount++; 
        }
        c = p; 
    }
    free(rowWord);
    fclose(flwd); 
    return wordStorage; 
}
```

The hash map works fine, this is the method that causes the issues, without it, there are no memory leaks.

Later in the code, I free the wordStorage array with this method:

```
void FreeWordStorage(char** wordStorage){
    int f = 0;  
    /* The Amount of words in each file, File 1, 2, 3 */
    int totalWordQuantity[3] = {132, 7420, 19829}; 
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i < totalWordQuantity[numLetters - 2]; i++){
        free(wordStorage[i]); 
        f++; 
    }
     
    free(wordStorage);
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things to fix it. Oddly enough, when I check it with integers, I'm allocating and freeing the same amount of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Valgrind is telling you that memory that was allocated by `FillHashMap()` was leaked, but that doesn't necessarily mean that that's where the error is.  You might get lucky, but you're much more likely to get a helpful answer if you can provide a [mre].

Comment: What is the significance and value of `numLetters`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think you've misinterpreted it (probably due to OP's weird naming scheme). The parameter name is `HashMap`.

Comment: Where did I suggest otherwise, @LHLaurini?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The function uses the parameter in calls to `AddRow2DLL` and `AddColumn2DLL`

Comment: Ah, so it does.  Dunno how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind's analysis indicates that the leaked memory was allocated by a bunch of `malloc()` calls by function `FillHashMap()`, and the only plausible candidate for those is this:

> ```
>             wordStorage[wordCount] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (numLetters + 1));
> ```

Function `FreeWordStorage()` appears to be correct for freeing the data allocated by `FillHashMap()`, so if some allocations are going unfreed then there are two main possibilities:

1. The pointer value returned by `FillHashMap()` is not later passed to `FreeWordStorage()`.  The latter function might not be called at all on the code path that is being exercised, or perhaps a modified or outright wrong pointer is being passed to it.
   Or,
2. Some or all of the pointers recorded in the allocated block returned by `FillHashMap()` are modified after being recorded, so that when it is called, `FreeWordStorage()` is ineffective at freeing the allocated memory.

Either one of those could be consistent with Dr. Memory's diagnostic, but whichever scenario applies, it does not appear to play out in the code presented in the question.  I am reasonably confident that your pointers are being mangled somewhere else in the program.